# LeetCode: Sliding Window Median C#

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, median

https://leetcode.com/problems/sliding-window-median/

> Median is the middle value in an ordered integer list. If the size of
>   the list is even, there is no middle value. So the median is the mean
>   of the two middle value.
>
> Examples: [2,3,4] , the median is 3
>
> [2,3], the median is (2 + 3) / 2 = 2.5
>
> Given an array nums, there is a sliding window of size k which is
>   moving from the very left of the array to the very right. You can only
>   see the k numbers in the window. Each time the sliding window moves
>   right by one position. Your job is to output the median array for each
>   window in the original array.
>
> For example, Given nums = [1,3,-1,-3,5,3,6,7], and k = 3.

[image]

> Therefore, return the median sliding window as [1,-1,-1,3,5,6].
>
> Note: You may assume k is always valid, ie: k is always smaller than
>   input array's size for non-empty array. Answers within 10^-5 of the
>   actual value will be accepted as correct.

Please review for performance. also I am not sure about GetID function is there a smarter way to get the same result of unique number and sorting for median?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace TreeQuestions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// https://leetcode.com/problems/sliding-window-median/
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class SlidingWindowMedianTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void ExampleTest()
        {
            int[] nums = { 1, 3, -1, -3, 5, 3, 6, 7 };
            int k = 3;
            double[] expected = { 1, -1, -1, 3, 5, 6 };
            double[] res = SlidingWindowMedian.MedianSlidingWindow(nums, k);
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, res);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void ExampleTestFailed()
        {
            int[] nums = { 1, 4, 2, 3 };
            int k = 4;
            double[] expected = { 2.5 };
            double[] res = SlidingWindowMedian.MedianSlidingWindow(nums, k);
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, res);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void ExampleTestOverFlow()
        {
            int[] nums = { 2147483647, 2147483647 };
            int k = 2;
            double[] expected = { 2147483647.0 };
            double[] res = SlidingWindowMedian.MedianSlidingWindow(nums, k);
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, res);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void ExampleFailed2()
        {
            int[] nums = { 5, 2, 2, 7, 3, 7, 9, 0, 2, 3 };
            int k = 9;
            double[] expected = { 3.0, 3.0 };
            double[] res = SlidingWindowMedian.MedianSlidingWindow(nums, k);
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, res);
        }
    }



    public class SlidingWindowMedian
    {
        public static double[] MedianSlidingWindow(int[] nums, int k)
        {
            var res = new List<double>();
            var med = new SortedList<long, int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
            {
                med.Add(GetId(i, nums), nums[i]);
                if (med.Count > k)
                {
                    med.Remove(GetId(i - k, nums));
                }

                if (med.Count == k)
                {
                    if (k % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        res.Add( ((long)med[med.Keys[k / 2 - 1]]  + med[med.Keys[k / 2]])/2.0 );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        res.Add(med[med.Keys[k / 2]]);
                    }
                }
            }
            return res.ToArray();

        }

        private static long GetId(int i, int[] nums)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt64(nums[i]) * nums.Length + i;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ID is a `long` created from 2 `int`s, so you can fit both `int`s inside this one `long` side by side:

```
long key = (long)nums[i] << 32 | i;
```

---

You have a lot of unnecessary `if` statement evaluations. You could get rid of them by adding the first `k` elements from the array into the list in a separate loop, and then starting a second loop from `i = k` that can safely do `med.Remove` and `med.Add` without `if`s.

`k` never changes, so instead of evaluating `k % 2 == 0` and `k / 2` and `k / 2 - 1` in every iteration, you can store the final value in a variable before the loop begins. Then in the loop you only need to call

```
res.Add(med[med.Keys[medianIndex]]);
```

or

```
res.Add( ((long)med[med.Keys[medianIndex]] + med[med.Keys[medianIndex2]])/2.0 );
```

---

Making `res` a list and in the end converting it into an array slows your code down a lot. You can make it an array (of size `nums.Length - k + 1`). Lists come with the overhead of their extra functionality, so you waste time not only on the conversion to an array but also on every time you add a number to the list.